# Using Homebrew python instead of system provided python

Tags: python, homebrew

I used Homebrew to install python, the version is 2.7.10, and the system provided version is 2.7.6.  My PATH environment variable is set to `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"`, so my terminal DOES know to look at the Homebrew bin folder first!

However, when I run python, it still defaults to 2.7.6, the system provided version (the interpreter that shows up says 2.7.6 at the top).  If I run `/usr/local/bin/python`, it runs 2.7.10, which is what I want.

If my `PATH` variable is properly set, then how is it possible that terminal still finds `/usr/bin/python` first?

Comment: How/where did you set the PATH variable?

Comment: 'which python' returns '/usr/bin/python'. This doesn't make sense because it should return '/usr/local/bin/python' because the PATH should tell terminal to look there first.

Comment: I am using zsh, and the PATH is set in ~/.zshrc

Comment: Use virtualenvwrapper.

Comment: I changed default shell to /bin/bash, restarted, ran python, and 2.7.10 launched.  I don't have a PATH variable set for bash and no ~/.bashrc, so what gives?

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping me out, but I solved the problem.  My zsh installation was installed with Homebrew, but I forgot to change default shell to `/usr/local/bin/zsh` instead of Mac's default zsh shell. That solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I installed Python 2.7.10 using brew. My PATH was set to `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` and which python returned `/usr/local/bin/python` (which is symlinked to Python 2.7.10.)

Problem went away when I closed and restarted Terminal application.